# Parse List of dictionaries in a dataframe into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following dataframe where I have a column with a list of dictionaries where I want parse it to new columns

```
 df = {
    'Column1': ['Data1', 'Data2'],
    'Components': [[{'a': 1, 'b': 'sd'}, {'a': 5, 'b': 'dfgf'}], [{'a': 3, 'b': 'fdg'}]],
    'Column4': ['Data4', 'Data5']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Where it should look like this

```
 df = {
    'Column1': ['Data1','Data1', 'Data2'],
    'a': [ 1, 5, 3],
    'b': ['sd','dfgf', 'fdg'],
    'Column4': ['Data4', 'Data4','Data5']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

```
|Column1 |  Column4 | a | b
:
|Data1   |  Data4   | 1 | sd
|Data1   |  Data4   | 5 | dfgf
|Data2   |  Data5   | 3 | fdg
```

I tried al these solutions

[Parse a column of stringified dictionaries in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59238706/parse-a-column-of-stringified-dictionaries-in-pandas)

[parsing a list of dictionaries in a pandas data frame rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59746744/parsing-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-a-pandas-data-frame-rows)
also this

```
exploded_components = df.explode('Components').reset_index(drop = True)

# Normalize the dictionaries in the exploded 'Components' column into separate columns
flattened_components = pd.json_normalize(exploded_components['Components'])

# Drop the original 'Components' column and concatenate with the flattened components
df_corrected = pd.concat([exploded_components.drop('Components', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True), 
                          flattened_components.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

still nothing worked because when trying  `df.explode('Components').reset_index(drop = True)`
return exactly the original df

Comment: `expl = df["Components"].explode().apply(pd.Series); out = pd.concat([df["Column1"], expl, df["Column4"]], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)`